# Will OCS work for instant messaging between two independent networks?

Tags: instant-messaging, ms-office-communicator

My understanding is that Office Communicator (and OCS in general) is targeted at a non-public network such as you would find within a typical large Co.

Can it be used for instant messaging between two independent companies?

If so, what kind of setup would be required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called "[Federation](http://www.microsoft.com/communicationsserver/cs14/en/us/federated-communications.aspx)".